# Error building a dotnet project on AWS codebuild

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I created a buildspec file for a dotnet framework project and in the build section specified the command below

```
'& msbuild   .\Gateway\Gateway.csproj /t:"Restore;Clean;Build" "-p:Configuration=Release;ReferencePath=C:\IntegrationServices\packages;OutDir=..\output\gateway;RestorePackagesPath=C:\IntegrationServices\packages" -m '
```

But got the error message below:

> Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error
> while executing command: & msbuild   .\Gateway\Gateway.csproj
> /t:"Restore;Clean;Build"
> "-p:Configuration=Release;ReferencePath=C:\IntegrationServices\packages;OutDir=..\output\gateway;RestorePackagesPath=C:\IntegrationServices\packages"
> -m . Reason: exit status 1

What could be the possible solution?

I tried double checking the commands for any typo and also cd into the path to my project to inspect the file paths